# Efficient way to assign positions to longest match

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, julia

I have been bending my head about this one for a bit. The data I have is quite simple. Something like this:

```
Position  match IDs
1         1, 5, 8
2         1, 10, 30
3         10, 40, 70
4         1, 10, 90, 100, 200, 203, 300
```

I want to assign each `Position` to the "longest" match, in this case:

```
Position  match ID
1         1
2         10
3         10
4         10
```

For position `2` we have options 1, 10, and 30. To get their lengths we have to check how many consecutive positions each match covers:

```
Match ID   covers positions
1          1-2 (also 4, but it’s not consecutive anymore)
10         2-4
30         2
```

So the longest match for position 2 is 10, covering 3 positions.

NOTE: the actual data has thousands of unique match id so making a matrix of all of them first for example is too memory intensive.

---

A solution I thought of is something like this but I feel like there should be a much easier way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

text = """Position  matches
1         1, 5, 8
2         1, 10, 30
3         10, 40, 70
4         1, 10, 90, 100, 200, 203, 300"""

d = defaultdict(list)

# Get all the positions each match occurs in
n_data = 0
for (i, line) in enumerate(text.splitlines()):
    if i == 0:
        continue 
    else:
        n_data +=1 
        position, matches = line.split("         ")
        for match_id in map(int, matches.split(", ")):
            d[match_id].append(int(position))


# Find consecutive positions to get full match coverage
intervals = []

for (match_id, positions) in d.items():
    start = positions[0]
    end = positions[0]
    for num in positions[1:]:
        if num == end + 1:
            end = num
        else:
            intervals.append((match_id, start, end))
            start = num
            end = num

    # Append the last interval if there is one
    intervals.append((match_id, start, end))

# Only keep the max value
max_id = [0] * (n_data +1)
max_vector = [0] * (n_data + 1)

for interval in intervals:
    match_id, start, end = interval 
    match_size = end - start + 1
    for i in range(start, end+1):
        print(i)
        if max_vector[i] < match_size:
            max_vector[i] = match_size
            max_id[i] = match_id
    
# Print it 
for i in range(1, len(max_id)):
    print("Position{}: {}".format(i, max_id[i]))
```

I can implement the algorithm in Python or Julia so both are fine. Pseudocode is also fine.

Curious to see if there is a smarter way to approach this :)

Comment: What does "covers 2-4" mean?

Comment: @Barmar 10 covers positions 2,3,4 so 2-4

Comment: You're not clear about what "covers" means. Although after I posted my question I figured out that you mean that 10 is in the list of values for positions 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: match id 1 covers "1-2,4", isn't that also 3 positions, why isn't it considered tied with match id 10? Is contiguity also a condition?

Comment: @BatWannaBe yeah it should be consecutive cause it’s the max match per position. So for 2 it’s at max 1-2 as 4 is part of another region

Comment: And I assume you want the longest contiguous match for each position to cover that position, so the longest stretch of a match id being 5-12 would be irrelevant to position 3 or 14, thus you need to consider the other intervals of the match id. And are the positions guaranteed to go from 1 to N in order with no gaps? Important things to clarify, has implications for memory efficiency.

Comment: @BatWannaBe yeah 3 and 14 are irrelevant for 5-12, so you do not have to consider other intervals for a match id. Yes you can assume they are sorted

Comment: What is your goal? Simplify your code? Reduce memory consumption? Increase execution speed? Since these are usually trade-offs, you may want to clarify your constraints and priorities. Also, can you provide the actual data (or the code that generates it) for benchmarking?

Comment: I am confused about your implementation. Given the match IDs were `0,1\n2\n1\n1`, your (and @DanGetz's ) program would output `0 2 1 1`. But isn't `1 2 1 1` correct? Is this just a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: @ken that would be a tie case, both `0` and `1` cannot be extended left or right from position 1 and hence both are an interval of size 1 , therefore equal and both correct. That `1`  is part of another longer interval elsewhere is not relevant in this case

Comment: I see. So the correct term would be **adjacent** consecutive positions.

Comment: @ken that's interchangeable here? The positions are always consecutive and adjacent

Comment: As you said, "consecutive" can exist elsewhere. But "adjacent" cannot. There may be a more appropriate word, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way (Julia language):

```
text = """Position  matches
1         1, 5, 8
2         1, 10, 30
3         10, 40, 70
4         1, 10, 90, 100, 200, 203, 300"""

lines = readlines(IOBuffer(text))

# positions not really needed
positions = parse.(Int, getindex.(lines[2:end], Ref(1:10)))

matches = [parse.(Int,split(l[11:end],',')) for l in lines[2:end]]

r = reverse(argmax.(
  accumulate(
    reverse(accumulate(
      matches;
      init=Dict{Int,Int}()) do x,y
          Dict(e=>get(x,e,0)+1 for e in y)
      end);
    init=Dict{Int,Int}()) do x,y
        Dict(k=>max(v,get(x,k,0)) for (k,v) in pairs(y))
    end
))

println(
  join(
    ["Position  match ID", rpad.(positions,10) .* string.(r)...],
    '\n'
  )
)
```

which gives:

```
Position  match ID
1         1
2         10
3         10
4         10
```

The Algorithm is straight forward, sweeping the matches in forward and then reverse, while keeping running length of seqeunce of elements in forward, and finally finding the maximum in the reverse pass. It uses O(matches) memory.

ADDED: Another way with less `accumulate` and `reverse`:

```
r = foldl(matches; init=Dict{Int,Int}[]) do x,y
    d = Dict{Int,Int}()
    for v in y
        L = length(x)==0 ? 0 : get(x[end], v, 0)
        for i in 0:L-1
            x[end-i][v] = L+1
        end
        d[v] = L+1
    end
    push!(x, d)
end .|> argmax
```

Comment: O(matches) doesn't seem accurate, it should also depend on number of positions. For example, the lengths of `matches` and intermediate results in the reverse-accumulate expression are the number of positions, and there are duplicate match ids per entry, so each structure has the same scale as the file itself.

Comment: O(matches) means about the size of the `matches` variable (as the code shows), which is basically the size of the file. So yeah.

Comment: Thanks! the second one is a bit slower on a bigger dataset: 
`233.637 ms (4549929 allocations: 275.08 MiB),  484.176 ms (4530725 allocations: 234.85 MiB)`

Comment: In case of equally long matches, like `1,1,1` and `10,10,10` for a position which one would this code retain? Will that depend on the input order?

Comment: This wasn't in the original question but I see the `argmax` is it possible to for example say give me the `n` max match ids? So assigning a position to `n` longest matches instead of only the longest. Or would this make it much more complex being not 1D anymore?

Comment: Yes, getting the n best IDs is possible. And, yes, the output will depend on input order. Since the output can be ambiguous i.e. two IDs have same maximal streak length, it is natural to have such dependencies. Adding some tie-breaking info in the values which go through argmax is an option.

Comment: The line `accumulated_dict_arr[end-i][match_id]` can go out of index although not sure how to fix it. `BoundsError: attempt to access 1-element Vector{Dict{Int64, Int64}} at index [0]`

Comment: It can't go out of index, as `i` runs from `0` to `L-1` where `L` is has the length of the streak so far. So it basically updates all the positions of the streak. Maybe there is some off-by-1 bug in the way you implemented it.

Comment: @DanGetz don't think so, this for example fails for me `[[1, 5], [1, 2, 4], [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5]]` but with one less `2` it works again: `[[1, 5], [1, 2, 4], [2, 2, 4, 4, 5]]` (accummulate works fine for both)

Comment: This might be because of the duplicates? That doesn't really matter for my application then cause they will be unique

Comment: Ah, yes, the duplicates are bad. Just add `haskey(d,v) && continue` after the `for v in y`.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly, by "matrix" you're referring to a sparse matrix of positions by match IDs where data points are marked by 1s, 0s otherwise. In that case there are visible stretches along a match ID across consecutive positions, and for each position you want to print the match ID with the longest stretch.

In this solution, we assume the positions increase by 1 per line with no gaps, which is fair because data is likely recorded in order and gaps in stretches of match IDs would ruin the problem. This assumption allows for a couple things:

1. we don't need to load the whole data and process it; this could be adapted to a case where lines are read from a larger file.
2. At a position, we can track current stretches by whether the match IDs are present. If a stretch ended in the previous position, we go back and check if the stretch is a record length for each covered position, and all we need to store is the position it started at (though I map the position A:B to indices 1:(B-A+1) here).

Other design choices is reducing allocations like vectors and strings and a straightforward commented algorithm.

```
text = """Position  matches
1         1, 5, 8
2         1, 10, 30
3         10, 40, 70
4         1, 10, 90, 100, 200, 203, 300"""

function main(text)  
  # preallocate some things
  matchIDs = Set{Int}() # match IDs for 1 position
  trackedIDs = Dict{Int, Int}() # track match IDs and their starts
  longestmatchIDs = Tuple{Int, Int}[] # store match IDs with record lengths
  # need variables outside the loop's scope in order to use after loop
  index = 0
  position = 0

  # lazy iterator over the lines, skips the 1 header line
  # parse line, track match ID stretches, and find record lengths
  for line in Iterators.drop(eachsplit(text, "\n"), 1)
    index += 1
    position = parseline!(empty!(matchIDs), line)
    checktrack!(trackedIDs, longestmatchIDs, index, matchIDs)
  end

  # update record lengths from all remaining tracked IDs
  for trackedID in keys(trackedIDs)
    start = pop!(trackedIDs, trackedID)
    stretch_length = index - start + 1
    for pastindex in start:index
      record = longestmatchIDs[pastindex]
      if record[2] < stretch_length
        longestmatchIDs[pastindex] = (trackedID, stretch_length)
      end
    end
  end

  # print positions and record match IDs, like in example
  # can infer first position from final position and length
  firstposition = position - length(longestmatchIDs) + 1
  for (p, ID) in zip(firstposition:position, longestmatchIDs)
    println("Position $p: $(ID[1])")
  end
end

function parseline!(empty_matchIDs, line)
  # parse position and lazy iterator of match IDs
  # regex delimiter r",? +" (probably) means optional comma then any spaces
  position, matchIDs = Iterators.peel(eachsplit(line, r",? +"))
  for matchID in matchIDs  push!(empty_matchIDs, parse(Int, matchID))  end
  return parse(Int, position)
end

function checktrack!(trackedIDs, longestmatchIDs, index, matchIDs)
  push!(longestmatchIDs, (-1, -1)) # initial value for no ID at index

  # check if each tracked ID's stretch ended in last line
  # update record lengths for a stretch's positions if so
  for trackedID in keys(trackedIDs)
    if !(trackedID in matchIDs)
      start = pop!(trackedIDs, trackedID)
      stretch_length = index - start
      for pastindex in start:(index-1)
        record = longestmatchIDs[pastindex]
        if record[2] < stretch_length
          longestmatchIDs[pastindex] = (trackedID, stretch_length)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # if match IDs aren't already tracked, new stretch at this index
  for matchID in matchIDs  get!(trackedIDs, matchID, index)  end
  return nothing
end
```

Comment: Cool! Let me go through it to see if I get it :)

Comment: Check if it's correct and how it scales on a larger dataset. There are still allocations: 1) making strings when parsing each line, and 2) sets/dicts reallocate larger internal buffers when they get too full (helps that I also remove entries, which does not reallocate). Also bear in mind that this has to check previous positions for record lengths more often, whenever a stretch ends; this is just the cost of iterating lines and saving memory, we don't compute all the stretches' lengths at once here or copy each across all its positions, so we can't compare all at once per position either.

Comment: Seems to work on the test cases I can think of :) Another advantage is that this still works even though the match ids aren't sorted.

Answer (score 0):

One memory efficient approach would be to keep track of only the match IDs currently on consecutive appearances, and delete all their related data entries once they no longer appear in the current record from the input lines being iterated through.

Related data of a match ID include the starting position of its first appearance in the current streak (`starting_position_of_match`), a set of match IDs that have not finished their consecutive streaks given a position (`matches_of_position`), and when that set becomes empty because all match IDs have finished their consecutive appearances, a dict that maps positions to their match IDs with their calculated consecutive counts (`consecutive_count_of_position`). To calculate the number of consecutive appearances, we need a mapping of position-to-row number (`row_of_position`) because position numbers may not necessarily be incremental, and we also need its reverse mapping (`position_to_row`) to get positions from rows as we iterate through rows where a finishing match ID appears.

With this approach, the space complexity would be *O(n x m)*, where *n* is the average number of consecutive appearances of match IDs, and *m* is the average number of matches in a position. As you see, most importantly, the space complexity does not increase with the number of records or the file size:

```
import re
from io import StringIO
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain

text = """Position  matches
1         1, 5, 8
2         1, 10, 30
3         10, 40, 70
4         1, 10, 90, 100, 200, 203, 300"""

matches_of_position = {}
consecutive_count_of_position = {}
starting_position_of_match = {}
row_of_position = {}
position_of_row = {}
file = StringIO(text)
next(file)
for row, line in enumerate(chain(file, ['-1'])): # -1: a non-existent position to handle the last record consistently
    position, *matches = map(int, re.split(r',?\s+', line.rstrip()))
    matches_of_position[position] = matches = set(matches)
    row_of_position[position] = row
    position_of_row[row] = position
    for match in starting_position_of_match.keys() - matches:
        starting_position = starting_position_of_match[match]
        consecutive_count = row - row_of_position[starting_position]
        for r in range(row_of_position[starting_position], row):
            p = position_of_row[r]
            consecutive_count_of_position.setdefault(p, {})[match] = consecutive_count
            m = matches_of_position[p]
            m.remove(match)
            if not m:
                print(f'Position{p}: {max(consecutive_count_of_position[p].items(), key=itemgetter(1))[0]}')
                del matches_of_position[p], consecutive_count_of_position[p], row_of_position[p], position_of_row[r]
        del starting_position_of_match[match]
    for match in matches - starting_position_of_match.keys():
        starting_position_of_match[match] = position
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRNj9owEL37V4y4xG5NFJatul0J9dxTK/VIEYpYB6zGduQM210hfjsdJzEQUqCRYsx8@r15cfWOG2enT5U/HLSpnEfwihXeGdAOOstP9Nquv31v7a5SPkfno1ejMmuFqHyXRzt0rqxjwGqTa8sYqjeEGYxGox@u1qidBTA5rjaqZhOIz0TCJwlP7OHcMskkTDM2PdnI8Ejv54w9XgZ@ycIvLQ/tMg25GbVlrGu3dMWyimeYwW7PVs7WarVF/aqWK7e1OAypMfdINBzNIaQp2Pq9@zNMOo@lgNZY6FLRLrLKAzGCWVp5cAlWELkULaHUVoG2oOzWBNIVb7hswiTMk/EkWQjxzAL62ErChw4m9TB5xbVFSUNN66rUyH0iv/6qPyZt8dTXdIqKCyGaIv8gaB43i6ZerFwr5N2/NvUCfy@NfL0zdnTM6Q3uaG5iAviWVgJ@nfT0t3qvuYBxPFPLQngGSeG4VwvNm3VxzB5IoT0/NbpEOKh5KtJMMADwuV0rfj9ThurihKFh64yaI2OLXshN3aY0oxdV5NsSeSVJeaLDSnUHib2y5jTq/kz73U3qlXGvqhWC6Pl0AdYhmD6kBhbJnpSexFtgV@2fYWfyN34TDTVPw1VDQ5dAw5@d7h0@EWKeLfaJGDR7UeUVJBLutZNDTZPtxkRCs/8TWk/k8aMa35f7DZFf9jkTz@HwFw)